# Where does Docker insert DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM env variable?

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I use `direnv` and since I'm running Docker on M1 some containers don't run unless I specify `linux/amd64`. The problem is if I add it as env variable in the directory it builds all images as `linux/amd64`, how exactly does it read the env variable?

Just putting `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` means docker prefixes that for every build command?